# NoClassDefFoundError when using an enum on deployed app

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, enums, noclassdeffounderror

I've got an Enum `Provider` in my 'main' project. In my server project (using Servlets and Google App Engine) i've linked to this project. I can use classes from this main project in my Server project, however when accessing values from my Enum I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: gamemain/network/Provider
```

I get this when I for example run the server project and then use the enum. Why is this only with this enum but not with other classes? What can I do about it?

---

EDIT: 
I've 'solved' it by manually copying the Provider.java file from the main project into the server project. However this isn't a solution to the problem, rather a hack since I now have to maintain 2 copies. I'm still looking for an answer to this question: Why are all classes exported, but not my Enums (resulting in a NoClassDefFoundError)?

Comment: Is your enum an inner class? How do you instantiate it?

Comment: I've tried it both within another class and in a separate file. I instantiate it by `Provider p = Provider.values()[index];`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's not enough to link a project. You have to export classes that are used on server-side (or the entire project, if it's not too large) into a `.jar`, and add it to the `war/WEB-INF/lib` directory. Otherwise they will not be available to an App Engine instance.

Comment: I actually have my main project checked under 'order and export' to be exported completely. And besides that, it does work for normal classes, so why not for my enum?

Comment: I guess it is because the compiler creates a helper class for switch statements using enums, and for some reason this helper class is not exported into the dependent project.

Comment: If this is the case, would you know of a way to actually export it into the dependent project?

Comment: Exporting dependent project in a jar fixes this problem for me. I hope someone knows a better way.